# how can a call to a function return a string only the first time and undefined thereafter

Tags: javascript

Basically, the first time hello() is run it should print "Hello" to console and thereafter should print undefined... how could one do that?

```
function Hello(){
 return  "Hello";  
 }

function foo(fn){
 //not sure how to approach this
}

var hello = foo(Hello);
hello(); // return Hello
hello(); // return  undefined
hello(); // return  undefined
```

Comment: Is this homework? Because it looks like homework. Hint: there is a scope outside the function, variables defined there are accessible in the function.

Comment: function `Hello()` can take a `int` parameter say `callcount`. if it's more than 1 .. return undef;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple ways to do this, but they involve creating a variable outside of the function to keep track of whether the function has run and/or how many times it has run.

For the latter case:

```
var counter = 0;
```

Then, run your function as normal and, if it's not the first time, return `undefined`:

```
function foo(){
    if(counter < 1){
        counter++;
        return "Hello";
    }else{
        return undefined;
    }
}
```

That's expandable, so you could change the condition for the `if` statement if you wanted it to return `"Hello"` multiple times.

If this is your only use case, it would be better to use a Boolean:

```
var hasRun = false;
function foo(){
    if(hasRun){
        return undefined;
    }else{
        hasRun = true;
        return "Hello";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this example:

```
function Hello() {
    return "Hello";
}

function foo(fn) {
    var ctx = {};
    ctx.flag = false;
    ctx.run = function() {
        var rtn = this.flag ? undefined : fn();
        this.flag = true;
        return rtn;
    };
    return function () {
        return ctx.run();
    };
}

var hello = foo(Hello);

alert(hello());
alert(hello());
alert(hello());
```

Answer (score 0):

This approach uses a closure to wrap your original function.

It also works when you create multiple instances of `foo` as it keeps their call states separately and it does not pollute the global scope.

```
function Hello(){
  return  "Hello";  
}

function foo(fn) {
  var firstCall = true; //define the marker for first call
  return function() { //return the function that will be "hello()"
    //check for first call and decide what to return
    return firstCall
      ? (function() {
          firstCall = false; //mark that first call has been done
          return fn.call(); //return the result of Hello
        })()
      : undefined; //return undefined
  };
}

var hello = foo(Hello);
//wrapped your calls in document.writeln to see the result
document.writeln(hello()); // return Hello
document.writeln(hello()); // return  undefined
document.writeln(hello()); // return  undefined
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/bkX2d/